# Transiting in ARN Stockholm with Checked Baggage

Tags: luggage, transit-visas, check-in, stockholm, arn

I hope you can assist me please. I want to book a flights

## 1. KBP to ARN @ Evening of 10 July [Kyiv, Ukraine] -

```
                 Ukraine Intl Air 171 [Arriving at ARN Terminal 5]
```

## 2. ARN to AKL (Via Doha) @ Morning of 11 July [Auckland, New Zealand]

```
                [Departing from ARN Terminal 5] Qatar Airways 172 and Qatar Airways 920
```

Tickets #1 and #2 will be separate.
I will have baggage checked that needs to be collected.
Can I collect my Baggage from UIA and Check in to QA inside Transit zone of Terminal 5.

Do I need Transit Visa?
I am a Philippine Passport Holder with a visa to go to New Zealand.
Please assist, I am hoping to Book the tickets ASAP.
I hope you can assist ASAP please.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

If you collect your baggage, you will need to leave the transit zone and check it in for the next flight.

To get out of the transit zone, you would need to go through the passport control, which means you do need a Schengen or Swedish national visa.